# unparseable date with timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat, parseexception

I have to parse this two date

```
private static final String d1 = "2013­-04­-02T08:37:56Z";
private static final String d2 = "2013-­04-­02T10:37:56+02:00";
```

for the first one I'm using the pattern

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

and for the second one I'm using

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
```

but I'm always getting

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ....
```

here my test code:

```
private static final String d1 = "2013-­04­-02T08:37:56Z";
private static final String d2 = "2013-­04­-02T10:37:56+02:00";

private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE2 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE);

        Date d = df.parse(d1);
        System.out.println("d1 = " + d);

        df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE2);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
        Date dt = df.parse(d2);
        System.out.println("d2 = " + dt);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Remove "-" char in your format

Comment: i don't know why, the minus was removed copying the code... but i have them... i edited and corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DateFormat Definition is wrong:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE = "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE2 = "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
```

There are no minus sign in the string

**UPDATE**:
After you have updated your question, I think the `-` sign is not the minus sign. It only look so. Replace this signs. and try again.

Comment: Hi jens, i don't know why the minus was removed copying the code... but i have them... i edited and corrected it

Comment: Hi Jens... that was... maybe copy and past from source to my code uses a character that was like the minus but not it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your [HYPHEN-MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) characters may have been replaced with [HYPHEN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm) or [en dash or em dash characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). Be sure to use only text editors with your programming, never word-processors or formatted email/messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Formatter` as follows.

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE = "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIMEZONE2 = "yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
```

However, I would recommend using `JodaTime` for this purpose. JodaTime has better functions. Using JodaTime you can do something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
DateTime dateTime = df.parseDateTime("2013­-04­-02T08:37:56Z");
Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting your examples to Hex, it seems you are not using normal hyphen (`0x2D`) but a similar character (`0xC2AD` according to my notepad++ converter) called 'soft hyphen'.